# JPA2 + Hibernate 4.3 + Infinispan 6.0: clear cache

Tags: infinispan

when I use JPA2 + Hibernate 4.3 + Infinispan 6.0 and call

```
entitymanager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll()
```

the caches are NOT cleared.

If I invoke the clear command via JMX on a certain cache it works.

My config is empty:

http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-6.0.xsd"
      xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:6.0">

What is the problem here?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Eviction is DISABLED by default in 6.0. If you want to use this feature, you have to configure it.

See: http://infinispan.org/docs/6.0.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_more_defaults

> By default when no eviction element is specified, no eviction takes place.

Comment: I think that this config affects only automatic eviction, not explicit. And it does not explain that it works via JMX.